# Need help to plot / display multiple prices above bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have created this indicator that shows me my 1.5:1 , 2:1 and 3:1 RR lines. The lines are based on the previous candles High and low. High being my entry for long and low being my SL.  I would like to display the price next to the 1.5:1, 2:1 and 3:1 lines.
I have a simple label below the bar already showing me High, Low and half range. I just can't work out how to display only the price according to my lines.

Ideally I would like the price lablels to look like this

[Price Label RR Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTQNK.png)

Not a programmer but I can read a manual. sometimes I just need a nudge in the right direction to work it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="RR lines", overlay=true,max_labels_count=500)


//Input Options Full Range

fullRangeLong = input.bool(false, "FR Long")
fullRangeShort = input.bool(false, "FR Short")

//Time Options Input

i_hour = input.int(1, "Time (HH:mm)",0, 23, 1, inline = "A") 
i_minute = input.int(0, ":",0, 59, 1, inline = "A")

// create options for the different days of the week. 

i_sunday = input.bool(true, "Sunday") 
i_monday = input.bool(true, "Monday") 
i_tuesday = input.bool(true, "Tuesday") 
i_wednesday = input.bool(true, "Wednesday")
i_thursday = input.bool(true, "Thursday") 
i_friday = input.bool(true, "Friday") 
i_saturday = input.bool(true, "Saturday")



start = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2023 12:00 UTC+0"), "Start") 
end = input.time(timestamp("16 Nov 2023 12:00 UTC+0"), "End")



// Parameters
candleRange = (high-low) 
halfRange = (candleRange / 2)



//@variable Checks the time of the candle and gets the day of the week as represented by numbers 1-7, starting on Sunday. 

todayDay = dayofweek(time)

// Define Time for Candle 

candleTime(_hour, _mins) =>
    // Created 2 variables that need to be true in order to return true.
    isTimeMatch = hour == _hour and minute == _mins 
    isTodayShown = switch todayDay 
        1 => i_sunday 
        2 => i_monday 
        3 => i_tuesday 
        4 => i_wednesday 
        5 => i_thursday 
        6 => i_friday 
        7 => i_saturday 
    
    isTimeMatch and isTodayShown


// Full Range RR Lines Long//

if time >= start and time <= end and candleTime(i_hour, i_minute) and (fullRangeLong == true)

     //Buy Price
    line.new(x1=time, y1=high, x2=time + 86400000, y2= high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.yellow),
     // Stop Loss
    line.new(x1=time, y1= low, x2=time + 86400000, y2= low,xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.white)
    //1:1
    line.new(x1=time, y1= high + (candleRange*1.5), x2=time + 86400000, y2=high + (candleRange*1.5), xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
    //2:1
    line.new(x1=time, y1= high+ (candleRange*2), x2=time + 86400000, y2= high + (candleRange*2), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    //Take Profit 3:1
    line.new(x1=time, y1= high + (candleRange*3), x2=time + 86400000, y2= high + (candleRange*3), xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.orange),

     myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, color=color.white,
          style=label.style_label_up, size=size.small, 
          text =
               "H: "+ str.tostring(high) +
               "\nL: " + str.tostring(low) + 
               "\nR: " + str.tostring(candleRange)) 

    // Modify the label's y-axis behaviour; show it below the price bar
    label.set_yloc(id=myLabel, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

// Full Range RR Lines Short//
  
if time >= start and time <= end and candleTime(i_hour, i_minute) and (fullRangeShort == true)

     // Buy Price
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = low, x2 = time + 86400000, y2 = low, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.yellow)
    //Stop Loss
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = high, x2 = time + 86400000, y2 = high, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.white)
    // 1:1
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = low - (candleRange*1.5), x2 = time + 86400000, y2 = low - (candleRange*1.5), xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
    //2:1
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = low - (candleRange*2), x2 = time + 86400000, y2 = low - (candleRange*2), xloc = xloc.bar_time)
     // 3:1 Take Profit
    line.new(x1 = time, y1 = low - (candleRange*3), x2 = time + 86400000, y2 = low - (candleRange*3), xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.orange),

     myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, color=color.white,
          style=label.style_label_down, size=size.small, 
          text =
               "H: "+ str.tostring(high) +
               "\nL: " + str.tostring(low) + 
               "\nR: " + str.tostring(candleRange)) 
             

    // Modify the label's y-axis behaviour; show it above the price bar
    label.set_yloc(id=myLabel, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

I have tried to implement yloc = yloc.price into the myLabel but can't seem to get it to work. when I define x and y as I did with the simple label below the bar it doesn't display anything when I then add xloc = and yloc = yloc.price.